# p:dataTable - toggle rowEdit via menuButton

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have a `p:dataTable` where the last column contains a `p:menuButton` to provide some options for the corresponding row, such as 'delete' and 'edit' (there are more, which is the reason why I want to combine these options in a single column).

**How can I toggle the table's row editor using the menuItem ('edit'), so that the behaviour would be the same as if i clicked the `p:rowEditor`-icon (which I do not render at all).**

Code snippet:

```
<p:datatable ... >
  ...
  <p:column>
    <p:menuButton>
      ...
      <p:menuItem value="Edit" onclick="[what to put here?]"/>
    </p:menuButton>
  </p:column>
</p:datatable>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to call the PrimeFaces javascript for the widget directly, but there's a much easier solution.  Simply append your extra functionality to the column that contains the p:rowEditor tag.

For example, here's how to append a delete link command after the row edit icons:

```
<p:dataTable var="record" ... >
 ...
 <p:column>
  <p:rowEditor />
  <p:cellEditor>
   <f:facet name="output">
     <p:commandLink id="deleteLink" action="#{editBean.delete(record)}">Delete</p:commandLink>
   </f:facet>
   <f:facet name="input">
    <div></div>
   </f:facet>
  </p:cellEditor>
 </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Appending buttons for each extra function is not an option for me (see question). My approach is to combine all functions in one component (p:menuButton). Thus, the 2nd part of your answer does not help me at all, sorry. 
Much more interestering is _how_ i could call the PF JS directly??

Comment: In that case, you'll have to crack open the primefaces javascript file and figure out their interface.  Then, you can write your own script to get access to the datatable jquery widget using the PF() function to perform the same functionality manually.  (Take a look at the PrimeFaces.widget.DataTable.bindEditEvents javascript function -- you'll see how they bind the click event to the icon.)  I extend primefaces functionality in this manner all the time, but be careful when you upgrade versions as their implementation may change and break your code.